# Memory usage OneVsRest sklearn

Tags: python, memory, scikit-learn

I'm having trouble with memory usage using sklearn's `OneVsRest` class in a loop for crossvalidation (we cannot use sklearns crossvalidation methods for a different reason not related to this question).

The setup for the classifier could look like something like this:

```
clf = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), OneVsRestClassifier(SGDClassifier(loss='log', n_iter=5, penalty=None, alpha=1e-7, average=True))
```

Using the memory_profiler module, the Memory usage looks about like this:

```
  Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
  ================================================
    (...)
     231   1092.8 MiB    911.7 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    (...)

  next loop:
     231   2001.8 MiB    897.4 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   2892.5 MiB    890.5 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   2928.1 MiB     35.6 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   2977.6 MiB     49.5 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   3009.2 MiB     31.6 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   3014.6 MiB      5.4 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   3019.4 MiB      4.8 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   3031.0 MiB     11.6 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
  next loop:
     231   3041.4 MiB     10.4 MiB       clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

As you see, the memory usage increases steeply in the beginning and then more slowly.

Using classifiers not using `OneVsRest`, the memory usage stays more or less constant, since the classifier is re-fit with new training data each loop. This is obviously the behavior I would expect.

Why is this happening? How can I prevent it? Is it a sklearn bug or something more low-level? Note that re-initializing the classifier would be bad for our current code.

Update:

I changed to code to reinitialize the classifier, and deleted it using clf key after getting the prediction and the problem remains. Furthermore, the allocated memory does not turn up using `pympler.summary` so it seems not to be a python object but a numpy array (as expected). Using `.sparsify()` does not change anything.

When running to the memory limit, the swap is being filled, so the OS does not seem to be able to reuse the memory.

Note that the above example is on a very small part of the dataset.